# jQuery.get() not able to find a file in the same directory when used in cgi script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cgi

I am trying to read data from a text file from the same folder as the code using `jQuery.get()`. This works perfectly when running as a normal HTML page, but when I tried to use it in my CGI script in the same way I am getting `404 (Not found)` when I check in the console. The text file is also in the folder in which the CGI script is saved. The code I am using is as follows:

```
function refresh() {    
    jQuery.get("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/TP.txt", function(data) {
        buff = data.split(',');
        data1 = buff[0];
        data2 = buff[1];
        });
    };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I managed to figure out that it was to do with the user and owner of the CGI folder, once I changed that to the same user and group as the web server the following code worked:

Comment: function refresh() {    
    jQuery.get("/TP.txt", function(data) {
        buff = data.split(',');
        data1 = buff[0];
        data2 = buff[1];
        });
    };

Comment: Has anyone found jquery used like this to not the most recent data from the text file when using google chrome? It updates immediately when using other browsers but for it to work on chrome I have to change the name of the text file and adjust the code accordingly each time I reopen the browser

Answer (score 0):

When making such requests, we should write the website address to the beginning of the address.

For example;

```
function refresh() {    
jQuery.get("HTTP://WWW.YOURURL.COM/usr/lib/cgi-bin/TP.txt", function(data) {
    buff = data.split(',');
    data1 = buff[0];
    data2 = buff[1];
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Enver, unfortunately that leaves me running into more problems. I am redirected to a https domain which is causing me to get 'blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'' error. I thought that the web address would not be necessary as the files are all contained on the same device, as I mentioned the request works fine in a HTML file.

Comment: When I add code to the python section of the CGI script to access the file using open() this also works fine.